# Map custom domain to Azure App Service subpage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I want to map a domain to a subpage of my Azure App Service.

- `mydomaim.com` should map to `myapp.azurewebsites.net/page1/`,
- `mydomaim.com?info=1` should map to `myapp.azurewebsites.net/page1?info=1`,
- `mydomaim.com/data` should map to `myapp.azurewebsites.net/page1/data`
- etc....

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have tagged api-management as well. So, on API Management service, you can use policies to intercept the request and redirect to a route of your choice. Have a look at Rewrite URL policy [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL) . In .Net, its recommended to configure routes for such scenarios. May be you can use a similar feature in your language platform node, java etc.